# How to increase VB resolution? (Ubuntu host, Windows 7 guest.)

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, display-resolution

The host is 14.04, the guest is Windows 7.

The maximum screen resolution I'm offered in the control panel of the guest is 1024 x 725.

My actual screen resolution is 1600 x 900 and I have a NVIDIA Geforce GTX960M graphics card.

How can I increase the screen resolution in the guest?

I already have the guest additions installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason I had this problem was because the VM was in windowed mode. It turns out that the larger screen resolutions only appear in the control panel when you have actually resized the VM window to a large enough size for the resolution. So,  I put the VM into full screen mode,  and the larger screen resolutions promptly appeared in the control panel.  I hope this will be useful to others too.

Answer (score 1):

You need the Guest additions try this

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms
```

then restart the VM to complete the installation.

Comment: I already have the guest additions installed. Sorry for not mentioning that.

Comment: sorry then :( its out of my knowledge !

Comment: @Fiksdal Using your own answer as a cite-link is not very smart. If you had any help in solving this, please leave a link, however if not, please do not post links back to the same question.

Comment: @DavidCole-GrammarPolice Got it, thanks. Jonayad, I solved the problem. You can read about it in an answer I've made to this question.